# Hash and protecting data in transit

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, security, tampering

I came across the below suggestion on AWS docs regarding protecting request data in transit:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html

***Protect data in transit**
To prevent tampering with a request while it's in transit, some of the request elements are used to calculate a hash (digest) of the request, and the resulting hash value is included as part of the request. When an AWS service receives the request, it uses the same information to calculate a hash and matches it against the hash value in your request. If the values don't match, AWS denies the request.*

Just wondering is it not possible for the tamperer to recalculate the hash from the changed values and replace the new hash with the original hash, so that server is not able to see any problem with the request?

Is hash getting creating using a secret key? And tamperer will not be able to create the new hash properly?

I am sure I am missing something here. Could someone please help.

Comment: I have the answer below in the same link:

Signing requests
To sign a request, you first calculate a hash (digest) of the request. Then you use the hash value, some other information from the request, and your secret access key to calculate another hash known as the signature. Then you add the signature to the request in one of the following ways:

1. Authorization header.

2. Query Param

So basically we rehash the hash using secret access key and add that to the request.

Comment: Note that the AWS docs contain *abysmal* implementation advice, including long complicated hand-rolled implementations of some of these operations. Libraries are available to do nearly all of it; avoid the v1 AWS Java SDK if possible, and I prefer jets3t for S3 operations.

Comment: By the way, this AWS approach is fundamentally the same as [JSON Web Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token), with the difference that JWT is a bit verbose but overall sensible, while AWS signatures might be the single worst hassle of programming to AWS.

Answer (score 2):

Those signatures are comprised of a cryptographic hash and a secret cryptographic key. For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC. That is why you cant temper with the data and re-hash.

Answer (score 1):

> Is hash getting creating using a secret key?

Yes, the "hash" referred to here is actually an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), and creating it requires your AWS secret access key.